# Breaking from default behavior of TabGroups and new windows

Tags: iphone, mobile, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Typically, opening a window in a tab is pretty straighforward

```
Ti.UI.currentTab.open( 
    Ti.UI.createWindow( {url: 'foo.js'} )
  , {animated: true }
);
```

However, this initiates the "navigation group" style of UI breadcrumbs.  A "back" button is automatically placed on the nav bar.

Is there any way to open a window, in the current tab, but start from a fresh history?  Or make a "lateral" move to a new window - essentially replacing the current?

To make sure I'm clear, consider this window hierarchy

```
     root
    /    \
 child1  child2
        /      \
   child3      child4
```

In each case, a specific user action will open one of two windows into the current tab.

What if I wanted for a button click on **child3** to open **child4** while respecting the above view heirachy? I wouldn't want "back" to go to **child3**, I'd want it to go to **child2**.  Like this

```
     root
    /    \
 child1  child2
        /      \
   child3----> child4
```

Or what if I wanted "back" to just be gone, effectively starting a new navigation history?

Comment: it is probably technically feasible but it would be a UX that is not inline with what a user would expect from an IOS application. Is this a question of can it technically be done or should it be done? I dont think I have ever seen an iPhone application that behaves in this manner.

Comment: Aaron is right, the closest you could do to make it feel okay for the users is child4 to child3 then child2. But you could also use a Modal window as child4 but still return to child2 once called from child3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish the "lateral" move by doing a non-animated close, followed by an open:

```
Ti.UI.currentTab.close( 
    child3
  , { animated: false }
);

Ti.UI.currentTab.open( 
    child4
  , { animated: true }
);
```

However, I do not think you can do this on the root window in order to start from a "fresh history".

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't even work.  Just as well - since I agree with Aaron's comment above.  The app *shouldn't* do this.  The fact that it's just not possible from a tech perspective makes it all the easier for me to go back to the project team with a rebuttal.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this child3 --> child4 behavior is very similar to what I get in a window which is predominantly displaying a web view with a local HTML document, and the HTML has a hyper link to another local HTML document.